# Loop through a DatagridView and check if string exist in first cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
private void cap_CapturingEventHandler(string file)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (file == row[0].ToString())
            {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

My application adds files into my `DatagridView`.  Each time a new file arrived i want to check whether this file is already exist in my `DatagridView` (first cell in row).

It seems that my example does not even compile.

Comment: What error do you get? Questions must **describe the specific problem**

Comment: It does not pass compiling

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke`? It doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Different thread calling this function and not the main

Comment: What does "does not pass compiling" mean?  Could you show the error message that you are getting that makes it so it "does not pass compiling"?

Comment: Checkout @Dierk's answer. that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following statement

```
row[0].ToString()
```

to

```
row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: could you please explain why, it makes the answer better for those looking at it from outside the question, and helps them to understand the concept better.

Comment: and I think it should be `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()`

Comment: I've edited your code from `row.cells[0].ToString()` to `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` If you feel it is wrong you can rollback